# Heroku Process exited with status 137

Tags: api, heroku, deployment

I have been trying for a few hours to to fix an error happening while deploying my API to heroku. For some reason the app crashes after a successful build and deploy. Here are the logs:

```
2020-09-29T18:51:11.845783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-09-29T18:51:13.125412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-09-29T18:51:13.191564+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-29T18:51:13.191564+00:00 app[web.1]: 12%|â–ˆâ–        | 160M/1.34G [00:17<02:32, 7.76MB/s]
2020-09-29T18:51:13.191575+00:00 app[web.1]: len(cache))
2020-09-29T18:51:13.213110+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:     Stopping parent process [4]
2020-09-29T18:51:13.309921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-09-29T18:51:37.221519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `uvicorn API:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}`
2020-09-29T18:51:41.378851+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:21300 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-09-29T18:51:41.379026+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:     Started parent process [4]
2020-09-29T18:51:55.186891+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-29T18:51:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-09-29T18:52:37.410983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-09-29T18:52:37.438890+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-09-29T18:52:37.667428+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-09-29T18:52:37.667428+00:00 app[web.1]: 1M/1.34G [00:19<04:02, 5.21MB/s]
2020-09-29T18:52:37.667428+00:00 app[web.1]: | 149M/1.34G [00:39<06:52, 2.90MB/s]
2020-09-29T18:52:37.668908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-09-29T18:52:37.742697+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-29T18:53:49.137457+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sumit-up-api.herokuapp.com request_id=254a0f86-271b-4dd4-b2e0-1cb12eba18b2 fwd="109.136.86.149" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Could you please indicate me the steps I should follow to isolate the error?

Edit:

my procfile contains one line:

> web: uvicorn API:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}

requirement.txt file content:

```
vega-datasets==0.7.0
altair==3.2.0
textract
requests
fpdf
pyttsx3
uvicorn
fastapi
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
git+git://github.com/P-mir/bert-extractive-summarizer.git
```

Comment: Can you post your proc file pls?

Comment: `uvicorn API:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}` host and port should be something you let Heroku define.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, my procfile seems to be O.K though. What else should I look for?